# dotnetopenauth with AzureAD b2c

Tags: webforms, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, azure-ad-b2c

I am using dotnetopenauth (version 4) to obtain an accesstoken for my Api. This works perfectly fine but i cannot figure out how i can read the profile information for the user (which is send back by Azure AD b2c).

1. The first leg of the flow is a request to the authorization endpoint. (basically a get request)
2. After the authorization the callback url is called. In my case this is callback.aspx.
3. On this callback page i'm running the following dotnetopenauth code:

`var authorization = Client.ProcessUserAuthorization();`

This will do another post again to the token endpoint. The response looks like this:

`{"access_token":"xxxx","token_type":"Bearer","not_before":1519920056,"expires_in":3600,"expires_on":1519923656,"resource":"6ee73e1a-6e96-4ed6-b7f8-a52c1379317a","id_token_expires_in":3600,"profile_info":"eyJ2ZXIiOiIxLjAiLCJ0aWQiOiIyYjIzMTFmMy04ZWNlLTQ3MzMtOWVlNS04ZWMxNzJiOTRjMDMiLCJzdWIiOm51bGwsIm5hbWUiOiJBbGZyZWQgQnJvY2tvdHRlciIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6bnVsbCwiaWRwIjpudWxsfQ","refresh_token":"eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ","refresh_token_expires_in":1209600}`

As you can see the profile_info is included (as a base64 string). But the IAuthenticationState has no property or function to get this information:

[image: test]

Is there a way to get this extra response data with dotnetopenauth?

Comment: I found the answer myself on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639522/dotnetopenauth-oauth2-accessing-extra-data?rq=1